# How to clean and structure a messy csv file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, csv, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I have a hard time formatting my csv files in a way easy to process in a pandas dataframe. I am using this https://figshare.com/articles/UMA_ADL_FALL_Dataset_zip/4214283 dataset of fall data to train a RNN model to detect people falling but the formatting is quite hard to clean up with the python csv reader and even with a more intelligent module clevercsv.

this is the code to itterate over the files and merge them into a Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import clevercsv as csv

csv_list = []
directory = r"C:\Users\20191678\OneDrive - TU Eindhoven\Engineering Design" 
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if '.csv' in filename:
        with open(filename, "r", newline="") as fp:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(fp.read(), verbose=True)
            fp.seek(0)
            reader = csv.reader(fp, dialect)
            rows = list(reader)
            csv_list.append(rows)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_list)
```

Would be great if anyone can take the time to solve this and make a structured dataframe! Or come up with another idea of cleaning this up.

[image: This is a snapshot of the excel file where all initial data is named each row and where at the bottom all sensor data is provided]

The csv file code itself:

```
% Universidad de Malaga - ETSI de Telecomunicacion (Spain)                         
% Date: 2017-04-14_23:38:23                                                        
% ID: Subject_01_ADL_Aplausing_1                                                   
% Name: Subject_01                                                                 
% Age: 67                                                                          
% Height(cm): 156                                                                  
% Weight(Kg): 76                                                                   
% Gender: F                                                                        
                                                                                    
% Type of Movement: ADL                                                            
% Type of Movement: FALSE                                                          
% Description of the movement: Aplausing                                           
% Trial: 1                                                                         
                                                                                    
% Number of Sensors: 5                                                             
                                                                                    
% Used Smartphone: LGE-lge-LG-H815-5.1                                             
% Smartphone's Accelerometer: LGE Accelerometer - Vendor: BOSCH                    
% --> Version: 1                                                                   
% --> Min - Max Delay: 5000us - 65535000us                                         
% --> Maximum Range: 16.000000263891405 G                                          
% --> Resolution: 1.2136514986004396E-4 G                                          
                                                                                    
% SensorTag's Accelerometer: MPU-9250 MEMS MotionTracking Device - Invensense      
% --> Maximum Range: 16 G                                                          
% --> Resolution: 0.00024 G                                                        
                                                                                    
% MAC Address; Sensor_ID; Position; Device Model                                   
%f8:95:c7:f3:ba:82; 0; RIGHTPOCKET; lge-LG-H815-5.1                                
%C4:BE:84:71:A5:02; 2; WAIST; SensorTag                                            
%C4:BE:84:70:0E:80; 3; WRIST; SensorTag                                            
%B0:B4:48:B8:77:03; 4; ANKLE; SensorTag                                            
%C4:BE:84:70:64:8A; 1; CHEST; SensorTag                                            
                                                                                    
% Sensor_Type:                                                                     
% Accelerometer = 0                                                                
% Gyroscope = 1                                                                    
% Magnetometer = 2                                                                 
                                                                                    
                                                                                    
% TimeStamp; Sample No; X-Axis; Y-Axis; Z-Axis; Sensor Type; Sensor ID;            
102;1;-0.1387496441602707;0.8868721723556519;0.3310287296772003;0;0
102;2;-0.1381397247314453;0.8865065574645996;0.3323715031147003;0;0
102;3;-0.1348443180322647;0.8895576596260071;0.3311501145362854;0;0
102;4;-0.1402153074741364;0.8866279125213623;0.3337142467498779;0;0
102;5;-0.1391168385744095;0.8862622380256653;0.3345684409141541;0;0
102;6;-0.138628289103508;0.8871164321899414;0.3346897959709168;0;0
102;7;-0.1367969810962677;0.8880935311317444;0.3412821888923645;0;0
102;8;-0.138628289103508;0.8883378505706787;0.3398165106773377;0;0
102;9;-0.1409481465816498;0.8901675939559937;0.3401837050914764;0;0
102;10;-0.1418023407459259;0.8891920447349548;0.3418920934200287;0;0
102;11;-0.1430221647024155;0.8882149457931519;0.3420134484767914;0;0
103;12;-0.143510714173317;0.8880935311317444;0.3422577381134033;0;0
103;13;-0.1439992785453796;0.8838210105895996;0.3379867672920227;0;0
103;14;-0.1431450843811035;0.8795484900474548;0.3353012502193451;0;0
103;15;-0.1438763588666916;0.8766187429428101;0.3331027626991272;0;0
103;16;-0.1429008096456528;0.8790599703788757;0.3321272134780884;0;0
103;17;-0.142656534910202;0.8779615163803101;0.3343241512775421;0;0
103;18;-0.1409481465816498;0.8801584243774414;0.3348127007484436;0;0
103;19;-0.1429008096456528;0.8816241025924683;0.3376195728778839;0;0
103;20;-0.1457076668739319;0.8821110725402832;0.3385966718196869;0;0
109;21;-0.1441206336021423;0.8832111358642578;0.3412821888923645;0;0
115;22;-0.1387496441602707;0.8832111358642578;0.3404279947280884;0;0
115;23;-0.1391168385744095;0.8822340369224548;0.3404279947280884;0;0
121;24;-0.1375298053026199;0.8843095898628235;0.3399394154548645;0;0
126;25;-0.1369199007749558;0.8868721723556519;0.337375283241272;0;0
133;26;-0.1375298053026199;0.8854080438613892;0.331394374370575;0;0
```

Comment: Could you please share a fragment of the CSV file in a code tag, not as a screenshot of Excel? Excel may have already interpreted the raw data in some way that's not what's exactly in the file.

Comment: I added the csv code. where the sensor data values continue for 6500 lines and i have to deal with around 750 files like this.

Comment: Do you need the header data somehow too (the `%` lines)? If you do, you will need some custom parsing code to read that first. Otherwise you could just skip all lines that start with `%` and feed the rest of the data to Pandas or whatever.

Comment: Yeah I actually need some of them, but how to seperate them knowing that the sensor values headers are not prefixed with %?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you going.

```
from pprint import pprint


def try_number(s):
    try:
        if "." in s:
            return float(s)
        return int(s, 10)
    except ValueError:
        return s


def read_umafall(fp):
    header_lines = []
    metadata = {}
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("%"):
            if ": " in line:
                key, _, value = line[1:].partition(": ")
                metadata[key.strip()] = value
            else:
                header_lines.append(line)
        elif ";" in line:
            data.append([try_number(c) for c in line.split(";")])
        elif line:
            print("???", line)
    return {
        "header_lines": header_lines,
        "metadata": metadata,
        "data": data,
    }


with open(
    "UMAFall_Subject_01_ADL_HandsUp_2_2017-04-14_23-33-21.csv",
    "r",
) as fp:
    result = read_umafall(fp)
    pprint(result["metadata"])
    pprint(result["header_lines"])
    pprint(result["data"][:10])
```

The output is e.g.

````
{'--> Maximum Range': '16 G',
 '--> Min - Max Delay': '5000us - 65535000us',
 '--> Resolution': '0.00024 G',
 '--> Version': '1',
 'Age': '67',
 'Date': '2017-04-14_23:33:21',
 'Description of the movement': 'HandsUp',
 'Gender': 'F',
 'Height(cm)': '156',
 'ID': 'Subject_01_ADL_HandsUp_2',
 'Name': 'Subject_01',
 'Number of Sensors': '5',
 "SensorTag's Accelerometer": 'MPU-9250 MEMS MotionTracking Device - '
                              'Invensense',
 "Smartphone's Accelerometer": 'LGE Accelerometer - Vendor: BOSCH',
 'Trial': '2',
 'Type of Movement': 'FALSE',
 'Used Smartphone': 'LGE-lge-LG-H815-5.1',
 'Weight(Kg)': '76'}

['% Universidad de Malaga - ETSI de Telecomunicacion (Spain)',
 '% MAC Address; Sensor_ID; Position; Device Model',
 '%f8:95:c7:f3:ba:82; 0; RIGHTPOCKET; lge-LG-H815-5.1',
 '%C4:BE:84:71:A5:02; 2; WAIST; SensorTag',
 '%C4:BE:84:70:0E:80; 3; WRIST; SensorTag',
 '%B0:B4:48:B8:77:03; 4; ANKLE; SensorTag',
 '%C4:BE:84:70:64:8A; 1; CHEST; SensorTag',
 '% Sensor_Type:',
 '% Accelerometer = 0',
 '% Gyroscope = 1',
 '% Magnetometer = 2',
 '% TimeStamp; Sample No; X-Axis; Y-Axis; Z-Axis; Sensor Type; Sensor ID;']

[[371, 1, -0.01265575457364321, 0.9133599400520325, -0.1938552260398865, 0, 0],
 [371, 2, -0.01839394308626652, 0.9126286506652832, -0.1926354020833969, 0, 0],
 [371, 3, -0.01802674867212772, 0.9129943251609802, -0.1948323398828507, 0, 0],
 [371, 4, -0.02352065965533257, 0.9167782664299011, -0.1969063729047775, 0, 0],
 [371, 5, -0.02315346524119377, 0.9209294319152832, -0.2019117176532745, 0, 0],
 [371, 6, -0.01888094283640385, 0.9211721420288086, -0.203375831246376, 0, 0],
 [371, 7, -0.0208351630717516, 0.9270316958427429, -0.2050857692956924, 0, 0],
 [371, 8, -0.01924813725054264, 0.9303271174430847, -0.2070384472608566, 0, 0],
 [371, 9, -0.01766111142933369, 0.9342340230941772, -0.2080155462026596, 0, 0],
 [371, 10, -0.01265575457364321, 0.9388721585273743, -0.2115552425384522, 0, 0]]
```,
that is

* first the header lines that could be parsed as key-value pairs
* other header lines
* the data

You can hopefully trust each file to have the data in the same order (`TimeStamp; Sample No; X-Axis; Y-Axis; Z-Axis; Sensor Type; Sensor ID`).
````